# Spring security for android app

Tags: android, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to consume a rest services from android.

I want the username and password is entered only once. Then the system can work without having to reapply username and password.

I do not know what would be the right way to do this.
Save the password on the phone seems a bit insecure, maybe it's just my paranoia. applications like facebook, store the password in the phone?

What I'm trying to do is generate a token, store the token on the phone, and send the token in the header in each request.
I do not know if it is the right solution. I can not find how to do this without the token lose the session.

I have also read about OAuth2, but I have not got any example of  a small application That Demonstrates the use, not that of Facebook, Google, Twitter.

I used a Spring Server to communicate with my Android app.

Comment: Maybe [Handling Credentials](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Credentials) gives you a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use OAuth2.0.
for more information refer to [this](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/).